# Identifying usernames with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, authentication

I have a program that registers and authenticates new users into a MySQL database. How can my program detect which user is which? By IP address? Never have understood this part. Say that user who logged in sends a message in chat, how can I make my program know which user sent that message?

Comment: Usually people provide some identifiable username or use their email address as a unique identifier. There's also [OAuth](https://oauth.net) which gives you a token that identifies someone using things like Twitter or Facebook login. IP addresses should be presumed to be completely random and liable to change at any time without notice, even from one request to the next, and to be shared by an unknown number of people.

Comment: Have you ever dealt with user management before in Java?

Comment: If you're wondering how people are identified from one request to the next you might be asking about the persistent session layer. Most of the time this is done by attaching a unique token to the session via a cookie and then using that to look up any persistent details like who's logged in. Most web development frameworks do that for you, so I'd encourage you to find one to help you there. Doing this by yourself from the ground up is an extremely challenging undertaking and you're liable to get it catastrophically wrong. For anything other than academic curiosity it's not worth doing.

Comment: do you know anything in authentication? registering? login? if not how did you logged in into SO?

Comment: I used MySQL to verify whether the name entered already exists and if not, create it. Then, I check whether password and name are correct on login. From here it's confusing because I cannot find a way to identify a user in a unique way, to know which user is sending requests